# How to marshal this COM type to C#?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have a COM object (IUnknown **ppunkObject) which would be returned by below method. How to marshal this object to C# code?

```
public int GetObject (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IMoniker pmkObjectName, 
                      out object ppunkObject);
```

The same in C++ form:

```
HRESULT GetObject(IMoniker *pmkObjectName, IUnknown **ppunkObject);
```

Comment: The C# declaration of this method [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.irunningobjecttable.getobject?view=netframework-4.7.2), be sure that is what you use.  The object reference should then be cast to one of the interfaces implemented by the object, that does require knowing what kind of object you got back.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! The object type is EnvDTE.DTE, which should be from the envdte.dll from the Visual Studio installation path. This com class doesn't implement IPersist etc. interface, so it is not serializable? Any magic can we do?

Comment: It works reasonably well out-of-process.  Last time I tried anyway, been a while.  Why you'd want to use IPersist is hard to guess.  Don't go there, it isn't.  Always favor a vsix add-in first.